# Printing certain number of words from file

Tags: c++, c++11, file

Other code review noted problems with commenting and non-C++ code. This post aims to follow up on those issues.

Please check:

1. Comments are appropriate
2. Code is not C

My test file contains:

> one two three four five six seven eight nine

```
//This app is an exercise/study: Etude fr1_x
// prints x number of words from file, without newline, as determined by
//      short wordCount
// in:
//      void printWord(std::vector<std::string> &word)
// the output is connected to a timer.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>

//number of times to repeat output when calling println();
//instead of writing:
//
//  println();
//  println();
//
//i can write:
//
//  println((count)2);
//
//
//also, because println(int i) is already defined
typedef unsigned short count;

//TODO - yank all print[ln] to header
void print(std::string str){
    std::cout << str << std::flush;
    return;
}

void print(char c){
    std::cout << c << std::flush;
    return;
}

void print(int i){
    std::cout << i << std::flush;
    return;
}

void println(std::string str){
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return;
}

void println(){
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return;
}

void println(count c){
    const short maxVal = 10;/*short-term control - might assign neg val to count
                              i did, just to test it.*/
    if(c>maxVal){
        println((count)2);//accidental recursion
        println("Error:");
        println("called 'println(count c) with invalid arg");
        println("required: param c<=10");
        exit(0);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return;
}

void println(char c){
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    return;
}

void println(int i){
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return;
}

void println(short s){
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return;
}

std::string prompt(std::string str){
    std::string prompt = (str + ": ");
    std::string input;
    print(prompt);
    std::cin >> input;
    return input;
}

std::string getFileName(){
    return prompt("\nEnter a file name");
}

//TODO - break it up - too nested - too conditional
void readFile(std::vector<std::string> &word){
    const std::string quit("quit");
    std::string fileName;
    std::string str;
    short kontinue = 1;
    do{
        fileName = getFileName();
        kontinue = fileName.compare(quit);
        if(kontinue != 0){
            std::ifstream file(fileName.c_str(),std::ios::in);
            if(!file.is_open()){
                continue;
            }
            //source:Thinking in C++, 2nd ed. Volue 1, Ch. 2: Introducing vector
            while(file >> str){
                word.push_back(str);
            }
            file.close();
            break;
        };
    }while(kontinue != 0);
    return;
}

void test(std::vector<std::string> &word){
    int size = word.size();//could be a problem, maybe use long
    println();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        print(word[i] + " ");
    }
    println((count)2);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        println(word[i]);
    }
    return;
}

void slp(){
    usleep(1000000);//val will become user input eventually.
    return;
}

void carriageReturn(std::string str){
    std::string blank;
    int strSize = str.length();
    for(int i=0;i<strSize;i++){
        blank += " ";
    }
    //inconsistent - not print()
    std::cout << "\r" << blank << std::flush << "\r";
    return;
}

//TODO - this is suspect - may be too complicated - refactor/simplify
void printWord(std::vector<std::string> &word){
    //how many values to print at one time from vector
    short wordCount = 4;//this will become user input eventually.
    short numRead = 0;
    int size = word.size();//could be a problem, maybe use long.
    //even better, inspect file to determine needs

    int rmndr = size % wordCount;
    int stop = (size-rmndr);
    int idx = 0;
    std::string str;
    while(idx < stop){
        str += (word[idx++] + " ");
        ++numRead;
        if(numRead == wordCount){
            print(str);
            slp();
            carriageReturn(str);
            numRead = 0;
            str.clear();
        }
    }
    if(rmndr){
        for(int i=stop;i<size;i++){
            str += (word[i] + " ");
        }
        print(str);
        slp();
        carriageReturn(str);
    }
    return;
}

int main(){
    //TODO - doWhile
    std::vector<std::string> word;
    readFile(word);
    //test(word);
    println();
    printWord(word);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Comments:**

- *The top comment block is good*.  When writing a program, describing it at the top will tell the reader what it is expected to do output.
- *Too much whitespace within some blocks*.  Some of your comment text are too spread-out, adding more lines and reducing readability.  Avoid this by making your comments as concise as possible.
- *Talking to yourself "aloud"*.  Comments written in the first-person could be rewritten more professionally:

  ```
  // short-term control - assign negative value to count for testing
  ```
- *"TODOs"*: They are okay, but should be kept simple:

  ```
  // TODO - break up nested and conditional parts
  ```
- *"val will become user input eventually" and book references*: We don't need to know these things.  They only help you, not us.

**Code is not C:**

Compared to your previous program revision, *this does look more C++-like*.  @Lstor's main point was to use `std::string`, which you're now doing in place of `char` arrays.

I'd recommend getting more familiar with [C++'s STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library).  `std::string` is part of this library, and there's much more to explore.  Use it whenever possible, and your code will become more C++-like, more concise, and more robust.  Here are two starting points:

- [Use this reference guide which describes each library and its purposes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)
- [Pick up *Effective STL* to learn how to use it properly](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201749629)

---

**Miscellaneous:**

- Your `#include`s could be sorted alphabetically for organization.
- Be aware that `<unistd.h>` is platform-specific.  This is not recommended if your program needs to attain portability.
- By default, `void` functions `return` on their own.  It's only necessary when the function may need to end early for whatever reason.
- The "print" functions are unnecessary and just clutter the program.  Just use `std::cout`.
- In `println()`'s `if`-block: It's best to avoid terminating with `exit()`.  Replace it with a `return` and try to fall back to `main()` for termination.
- `printWord()`'s reference parameter should be `const`.  This applies to any non-native data type (such as an object) that will not be modified within the function.
- `std::getline()` is preferred for a user-inputted `std::string`:

  ```
  std::string input;
  std::getline(std::cin, input);
  ```
- `size()` returns an [`std::size_type`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409348/iteration-over-vector-in-c/409396#409396), not an `int`.  Correct return types should always be used, and you especially shouldn't mix signed/unsigned types.

  ```
  std::vector<std::string>::size_type size = word.size();
  ```

  You also don't need to create a variable for this.  Just use the `word.size()` in the `for`-loop.
- `readFile()` is hard to follow and could be simplified:

  ```
  std::vector<std::string> readFile(std::istream& inFile)
  {
      std::vector<std::string> word;
      std::string fileStr;

      while (inFile >> fileStr)
      {
          word.push_back(fileStr);
      }

      return word;
  }
  ```

  It's best to check the file in `main()` so that it can terminate if the file isn't found.  In this function, an input stream (for the file created in `main()` is received and an `std::vector` is returned.  This is okay to do because of [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

Comment: +1, valid points. What do you mean with your last item? `string` is default-constructed to the empty string. Also, I don't agree with the *count* item. *Count* is a noun and is more concrete (and therefore better) than `UShort`.

Comment: @Lstor: It is?  I thought I once encountered problems on my own with that, but apparently not.  I'll take out the other bulletpoint as well.

Comment: Regarding `TODO`: I think it's perfectly valid to keep notes of TODOs in the code. Listing them at the top would make it like a very primitive bug tracker -- keeping them at the code in question makes it metadata. I'd keep them short and sweet, though: `// TODO: Read as input`.

Comment: I disagree about book references as a general comment, but think you're correct about this specific comment. In particular, when you're using a complicated algorithm, a book reference is useful. When you're just using standard library elements as designed, book references are noise.

Comment: @Jamal, "Talking to yourself "aloud". Comments" - I think you nailed it. I work/study alone and that is affecting things - I have to adjust my view. Thank you for your time and work.

Comment: @Jamal, "Just use the word.size() in the for-loop" - I thought using x.size() or x.length() meant the value has to be calculated for every pass of a loop so using a var to store the calculation result is  more efficient. Is it not a calculation?

Comment: @yas: A bit so, yes.  However, `x.size()` can be a bit more _readable_ while it's not very intensive since you're just calling an accessor (thus no extra operations since it's `const`).

Answer (score 6):

I can't help thinking that this seems somewhat...over-engineered. I think I'd consider something on this order as a starting point:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream in("one two three four five six seven eight nine");

    std::cout << std::distance(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in),
                               std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
}
```

Here I've embedded your test input into the program, but the same idea applies equally well to an external file.

Comment: "over-engineering" caught my attention; I am glad to have reference to the idea - thank you. From : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001120/what-is-over-engineering-as-applied-to-software
"...Implement things when you actually need them, never when you just foresee that you need them."